# Break not working

Tags: php, function, break

I am looking for expert to explain why the FOREACH is not stopping after the UPDATE and break?

The code find position in 3x10 matrix, when it finds it and update the table it suppose to break and exit but it keep looping.. very very very strange.

```
checkPosUnder('x',array(100000));

function checkPosUnder($userToFill,$underUsers) {
    echo "<br>enter func Check on all this users:<br>";
    print_r($underUsers);
    $newGenUsers = array();
    foreach($underUsers as $curuser) {
        echo "<br>NEW LOOP<br>";
        //$underThisUser
        $freeq = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tueeunet WHERE username=?");
        $freeq->execute(array($curuser));
        $freeq->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $free = $freeq->fetch();

        if($free['under1']=='') {
            $updateQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE tueeunet SET under1=? WHERE username=? ");
            $updateQuery->execute(array($userToFill,$curuser));
            echo "1<br>";
            break;
        }
        elseif($free['under2']=='') {
            $updateQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE tueeunet SET under2=? WHERE username=? ");
            $updateQuery->execute(array($userToFill,$curuser)); 
            echo "2<br>";
            break;
        }
        elseif($free['under3']=='') {
            $updateQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE tueeunet SET under3=? WHERE username=? ");
            $updateQuery->execute(array($userToFill,$curuser));
            echo "3<br>";
            break;
        }
        else {
            array_push($newGenUsers, $free['under1'],$free['under2'],$free['under3']);
            echo "<br>";
            print_r($newGenUsers);
            echo "<br>";
            checkPosUnder($userToFill,$newGenUsers);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PLB where did you see the outer loop?

Comment: No bro, Break here doesn't stop the loop, i see "NEW LOOP" right after the echo "1". I also tried RERUTN; after the break and still see the echo again right after the foreach :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
break(2);
```

Manual does not mention IF's specifically but it is an encloser { } maybe `break` is just exiting the IF and not the foreach.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 2 levels in /home/dilobim/public_html/tueeunet/welcome.php on line 42

Comment: What output are you getting? When using just break;

Answer (score 0):

U can use a flag for it..

```
    foreach($underUsers as $curuser) {
    $updated = false;
            if($free['under1']=='') {
                $updateQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE tueeunet SET under1=? WHERE username=? ");
                $updateQuery->execute(array($userToFill,$curuser));
                echo "1<br>";
                $updated = true;
            }

    if($updated)
    Break;
}//Foreach
```

Answer (score 0):

possibly your code always enters in `else` part.

alternatively you can use flag in your solution

```
checkPosUnder('x',array(100000));

function checkPosUnder($userToFill,$underUsers) {
    echo "<br>enter func Check on all this users:<br>";
    print_r($underUsers);
    $newGenUsers = array();
    foreach($underUsers as $curuser) {
        $Break = false;
        echo "<br>NEW LOOP<br>";
        //$underThisUser
        $freeq = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tueeunet WHERE username=?");
        $freeq->execute(array($curuser));
        $freeq->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $free = $freeq->fetch();

        if($free['under1']=='') {
            $updateQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE tueeunet SET under1=? WHERE username=? ");
            $updateQuery->execute(array($userToFill,$curuser));
            echo "1<br>";
            $Break = true;
            break;
        }
        elseif($free['under2']=='') {
            $updateQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE tueeunet SET under2=? WHERE username=? ");
            $updateQuery->execute(array($userToFill,$curuser)); 
            echo "2<br>";
            $Break = true;
            break;
        }
        elseif($free['under3']=='') {
            $updateQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE tueeunet SET under3=? WHERE username=? ");
            $updateQuery->execute(array($userToFill,$curuser));
            echo "3<br>";
            $Break = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            array_push($newGenUsers, $free['under1'],$free['under2'],$free['under3']);
            echo "<br>";
            print_r($newGenUsers);
            echo "<br>";
            checkPosUnder($userToFill,$newGenUsers);
        }

        if($Break) { Break; }
    }
}
```